# Sort Tuples in a LinkedList formed using class constructor without using built-in functions - Python

Tags: python, sorting, linked-list, tuples, mergesort

I'm looking for help getting started with an assigned LinkedList sorting task. I have been given the starter code below and asked to come up with a suitable sorting method - I'm thinking MergeSort might work best? - but most examples I see online add to the LinkedList using an **addNode** function alongside a separate **Node** class so I'm unsure how to proceed with the code below as it specifies I should use *data[0][0]* for *self.name* and *data[0][1]* for *self.quantity* which is where I am struggling to extract the values for.

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.name = data[0][0]
        self.quantity = data[0][1]
        self.tail = None if (len(data) == 1) else LinkedList(data[1:])

# Shortened list to improve readability
fruits = LinkedList([("Apples",7),("Bananas",2),("Dragon Fruit",1),("Pomelo",14),("Grapes",65),("Cherries",43),("Pears",6),("Mangoes",31)])
```

I tried to iterate through the LinkedList but the solutions I tried involved converting to a list or use built in Python sorting functions (both of which I am not allowed to use for the task).

Additionally, I tried using a 'for in' loop as shown below, creating a **self.result** array and then appending **resultName** and **resultQuantity** as a tuple which I think is a partial solution but I haven't been able to find a way to solve this using the provided self.name (data[0][0]) and self.quantity (data[0][1]) attributes.

```
# Added to LinkedList class __init__
self.data = data
self.result = []
        
        for each_tuple in self.data:
            resultName = each_tuple[0]
            resultQuantity = each_tuple[1]
            self.result.append((resultName, resultQuantity))

print(fruits.result)
```

I assume there is probably an easy fix for this but I'm unsure how to proceed without changing the starting code.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: As this seems to be an assignment task, please include other constraints you may have. For example, are you allowed to alter/not use the starter code? Are there constraints in the form of time/space complexity? Are you required to add/remove from the list at a later time? Also be clear on how this is supposed to be sorted. Are you sorting it similar to the default sorting of tuple? Or only on the int value in the 2nd column? Lastly, you will likely get more replies if you ask about a specific problem, rather than asking for an entire solution to the given problem.

Comment: Thanks @Shorn - the results will be sorted by quantity, the int value in the 2nd column but I am allowed to sort the results using any sorting algorithm so no constraints on time/space complexity.
Additionally, I am required to print the LinkedList before and after being sorted so I believe it is fine to edit the existing LinkedList.
I actually wasn't hoping for the entire sorting solution but instead working out how to process the provided array of tuples using the specified values for self.name and self.quantity (data[0][0] and data[0][1]) as I am struggling to extract these values.

Comment: I hope you realise that `len` is a built-in function. That `LinkedList` class is memory inefficient, uses non-intuitive names (`tail` references a node that is not the tail of the list), lacks the notion of "head"...

Comment: Thanks @trincot - that's part of the starter code that I can't change and the references to data[0][0] and self.tail have made the task a lot more difficult than just using a separate Node class with self.data and self.next alongside a LinkedList pointing to the head instead.

Comment: @trincot `tail` is a `LinkedList`, not just a `LinkedListNode`, the name is fine.

Comment: Which attributes of the `LinkedList` objects are you allowed to change? Are you allowed to change `name` and `quantity`? Or only `tail`? Or none of them (so you must build a new sorted list)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm thinking MergeSort might work best?

Yes, that is a good candidate.

> most examples I see online add to the `LinkedList` using an `addNode` function alongside a separate `Node` class

You don't need an `addNode` function, since the `__init__` function already deals with *adding* nodes. Your work will be to *rewire* the existing nodes by altering their `tail` references.

The exercise only gives you one class, while other implementations use two classes: one for node instances, and one for the linked list instance having a reference to the head node of the linked list. Here however, the single class corresponds to what other implementations call the `Node` class -- despite the name `LinkedList`. There is no container class here that holds the head node reference. This you have to manage "yourself". But this is not a major problem.

> the solutions I tried involved converting to a list or use built in Python sorting functions

You shouldn't have to add code to the `__init__` method. The idea is that you create *another* method that will do the sorting.

This method should not create a list like `self.result = []`, as then you just move the problem of sorting to the standard list, and you are not allowed to use one anyway let be you could call `sort` or `sorted` on it. Moreover, the end result needs to be a sorted **linked** list, so you'd still have to copy the sorted list data back into the linked list. The idea of this exercise is that you sort the linked list without this extra data structure.

> there is probably an easy fix for this

No, there isn't, as you should not use any of that code that creates and iterates a standard list. So that code needs to be discarded.

You can ease your work by first creating an `__iter__` method on your class. This is not required, but it makes working on this exercise a bit easier, as this can be used to print the list or convert it to a standard list for debugging purposes. Related to that, we have a node content here that has two components: name and quantity. As we want to sort by quantity, it seems a good idea to have a method that returns this data as a **tuple**: tuples can be compared while sorting. This also gives a way to solve "ties" -- when two nodes have the same quantity we maybe want to use the name to define which one comes first.

Here are two methods I would add to the class:

```
    def tuple(self):  # To get the content of a node as a tuple, easing comparisons
        return self.quantity, self.name
    
    def __iter__(self):  # This helps to visualise the linked list
        yield self.tuple()
        if self.tail:
            yield from self.tail
```

With this in place, you can do things like:

```
fruits = LinkedList([("Apples",7),("Bananas",2),("Dragon Fruit",1),("Pomelo",14),("Grapes",65),("Cherries",43),("Pears",6),("Mangoes",31)])
print(*fruits)
```

...and it will print the entries in the linked list (with quantity as first tuple member). This is very useful when debugging.

### Merge Sort

As you suggested, let's go for merge sort. This is a recursive algorithm, and so you need a base case. The base case is when the list only has one element, i.e. when its `tail` attribute is `None`. In that case the list is already sorted and can be returned without any further action.

In the recursive case you need to:

- Split the list into two halves (partition):

  - The first half would start at the same node as before the split, so the only information we need back from this split is the reference to the first node of the second half.
- Sort each of the halves recursively
- Merge the two sorted halves

Let's make the `partition` method. We need to find a middle node, and for this we can use the [tortoise and hare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%27s_cycle-finding_algorithm#Tortoise_and_hare) approach:

```
    def partition(self):
        # Use Tortoise and Hare approach to find (almost) middle node
        slow = self
        fast = self.tail  # Start one step ahead
        while fast and fast.tail:
            fast = fast.tail.tail
            slow = slow.tail
        head2 = slow.tail  # Second half starts after the middle node
        slow.tail = None  # Disconnect the first half of the list from the second half
        return head2  # Return start of second half
```

Then we need a `merge` method that gets a second sorted linked list as argument and then merges the nodes of both linked lists into one linked list. We can take first order the two lists by their head nodes, take the first and then merge the rest of that first list with the second until one of the lists has no more nodes:

```
    @classmethod
    def merge(Cls, head1, head2):
        if not (head1 and head2):  # Base case: If at least one of the lists is empty,
            # ...return the other one
            return head1 or head2
        # Order the lists so that head1 has the node that should come first
        if head1.tuple() > head2.tuple():
            head1, head2 = head2, head1
        head1.tail = Cls.merge(head1.tail, head2)  # Merge rest and prepend head1
        return head1
```

Finally, we need the `mergesort` algorithm implemented:

```
    def mergesort(self):
        if not self.tail:  # Base case. When list has just one node, then it is sorted. 
            return self
        # Split list into two, sort the two halves recursively 
        #    and then merge the sorted halves
        return LinkedList.merge(self.partition().mergesort(), self.mergesort())
```

And that's it. Run as:

```
fruits = LinkedList([("Apples",7),("Bananas",2),("Dragon Fruit",1),("Pomelo",14),("Grapes",65),("Cherries",43),("Pears",6),("Mangoes",31)])
print(*fruits)
sortedfruits = fruits.mergesort()
print("sorted:")
print(*sortedfruits)
```

Comment: They've already embraced linear recursion in their `__init__`, you've already embraced linear recursion in your `__iter__`. How about also using it in `merge` as well, instead of the loop? I think it'll be nicer.

Comment: (With linear I meant the recursion depths. They take quadratic time. My suggestion for recursive `merge` would have linear depth and linear time.)

Comment: @KellyBundy, good remark. Done.

Comment: Why a class method? [My version](https://dpaste.org/FG2Oo).

Comment: I considered the calling code a bit easier to understand if both lists are passed as arguments. But it is just a matter of taste.

Comment: Ok. I thought maybe you thought of `head1.tail = head1.tail.merge(head2)` and realized that that doesn't work when `head1.tail` is `None`. That's why I do `head1.tail = head2.merge(head1.tail)`, as `head2` isn't `None`. (Taking advantage of that fact also makes my base case code shorter.)

Comment: Thank you so much @trincot for the response and clear explanations throughout, I really appreciate it! It makes way more sense now (I'm glad it wasn't a simple fix, in some ways, as I had spent a long time already trying to try to resolve the issue myself) and you went above and beyond what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

A simple selection sort solution, always swapping the smallest data to the current position and then going to the next position. It does take quadratic time, but you commented that you have no constraints on complexity, and your `__init__` as well as trincot's `__iter__` also take quadratic time.

```
def print_list(lst):
    print('LinkedList:')
    while lst:
        print(' ', lst.name, lst.quantity)
        lst = lst.tail
    print()

def sort_list(lst):
    while lst:
        mini = curr = lst
        while curr:
            if curr.quantity < mini.quantity:
                mini = curr
            curr = curr.tail
        lst.name, mini.name = mini.name, lst.name
        lst.quantity, mini.quantity = mini.quantity, lst.quantity
        lst = lst.tail

print_list(fruits)
sort_list(fruits)
print_list(fruits)
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLJTsMwEL3nK0bl0ESKEKFlUUUPLIJLQUgcqyoyzaSxcO1gu6B@ffE4ewEnB8@8N4vfTLm3hZKT61IfDmvBjIEFlx@YLbixswDcyTCHNOWS2zQNDYo8hoxZFlUoHXKeSrZFmHtoebZy/xD@3DFpud33KMkRxTIuHPyiJALPIRQoQ18J5nNIIkBhsNedx5bJbBUFwQm8FUpblJiBcBhYBXxbavWFoJFl7J0LVzzI9Y5b44r00izD0W1ZCjSj@CqKw9Edk@5z1jlZD5ptlIRHChzFCble1RaFcsaUrCfNSoq9vCDrvkCtOdnTieci0wTS/ZnJjSJokkTUNAlbai5tSi2HwthaU@8Mx71BjCMPfBdcIIhmMj0ujGPy@ylUt0bwqKU6r3s5YaR0r1Ldi3EKHrfyR8WtWwWXZ73TukrXIhWZgI5Nxw2TnN0O3PgkrT1kH9UYYHVRn619RP22@u0@c72M7b0TZxDRNBAP@2kiO7hP/k/PoDfLas@ioJO08fwmHQ4/)):

```
LinkedList:
  Apples 7
  Bananas 2
  Dragon Fruit 1
  Pomelo 14
  Grapes 65
  Cherries 43
  Pears 6
  Mangoes 31

LinkedList:
  Dragon Fruit 1
  Bananas 2
  Pears 6
  Apples 7
  Pomelo 14
  Mangoes 31
  Cherries 43
  Grapes 65
```